# HTML pretty view page for git diff

Tags: git, report, diff

Does any body know what tool is used to generate such a pretty diff report like
https://review.openstack.org/#/c/6670/4/exercises/floating_ips.sh,unified

(attention it shows changed lines and hightlights exact changes )

We are considering to receive git diff in HTML format to speed up code review.
Other variant for pretty view diff report.

Comment: gitk diff your/file/name